# ¿Cómo sacar los datos que son diferentes de una tabla en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subconsultas

Estoy intentando sacar los datos de una tabla que son diferentes a otra. Es decir, tengo la tabla A (users) que contiene los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo la tabla B (interacted_users) en la que guardo las interacciones entre perfiles:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es sacar los datos de las personas de la tabla A (users) que no estén en la tabla B (interacted_users) y que sean de la misma ciudad que un usuario en concreto, en este caso el usuario con el ID 9.

He probado a hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
select u.*
from users u, interacted_users iu 
where iu.main_user_id = 9 and iu.interacted_user_id != u.id and u.city = "Cordoba"
```

Pero me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado también a hacer una subconsulta de la siguiente forma:

```
select u.id, u.nick, u.city
from users u, 
    (
    select u2.* from interacted_users iu, users u2 where iu.main_user_id = 9
    ) us
where us.id != u.id and u.city = "Cordoba"
```

Devolviéndome lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porque a pesar de estar poniendo que los ID sean diferentes, me saca igualmente los señalados en rojo, que no deberían aparecer. Además se muestran repetidos.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pides es esto:

```
SELECT * FROM users
  WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT interacted_user_id
      FROM interacted_users
  ) AND city=(
    SELECT city FROM users
      WHERE id=9
  );
```

Pero tengo la sensación de que lo que realmente necesitas es esto otro:

```
SELECT * FROM users
  WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT interacted_user_id
      FROM interacted_users
      WHERE main_user_id=9
  ) AND city=(
    SELECT city FROM users
      WHERE id=9
  );
```

No necesitas excluir a todos los usuarios que hayan tenido alguna interacción, si no únicamente a los que no hayan tenido interacción el `id=9`.

Espero que sea lo que buscabas. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Exacto, es lo que necesitaba, la segunda query. Osea que la clave está en hacer la subconsulta en el where y poner el *NOT IN*, me quedo con la copla. Lo que no entiendo y no se si me podrías explicar es qué hace ese *DISTINCT*, porque he probado a quitarlo y me devuelve los mismos datos. Entiendo que es para sacar valores distintos, pero no entiendo qué hace en este caso.

Comment: Efectivamente, con o sin `DISTINCT`, el resultado es el mismo. Es meramente por una cuestión de eficiencia, como los duplicados no te hacen falta, ¿para qué mantenerlos en memoria? Con respecto al `NOT IN` hay más formas de implementar la resta, como con `LEFT JOIN`, pero sí, en principio filtra en el `WHERE` y visualiza en el `SELECT`, ya lo irás complicando gradualmente...

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, son cosas que no conocía. Probaré también a hacerlos con el ```LEFT JOIN``` para comparar y aprender. Me quedo también con el punto del ```DISTINCT``` que dices de no mantener los resultados en memoria.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo esto aquí:

[-JOIN SQL](https://diego.com.es/principales-tipos-de-joins-en-sql#:%7E:text=Principales%20tipos%20de%20JOINS%20en%20SQL%201%20INNER,pero%20al%20rev%C3%A9s.%20...%204%20OUTER%20JOIN.%20)

[-DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.